# d3 line graph connecting high to low

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This is my first post on stackoverflow so I hope i'm giving all information you guys need.

I'm having some issues with a d3 line graph.

I've got JSON output [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoV4K.jpg) looking like  which makes a graph looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obUP1.jpg). Problem is that my lines should be connecting from the first day to the last day, but instead my lines are connecting from the biggest value to the lowest value.

Below code makes the lines and connects them, and this is how it happens in all the guides/tutorials i've seen so far.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.y(function(d) { return y(d.count)})
.x(function(d,i) { return x(d.date) })
.interpolate("basis")
```

My JSON input is automatically sorted according to communication channel and count size. I'm running out of ideas since i've been bending over this issue for quite some time. If you have any ideas or need any additional information, i'm very grateful and willing to give anything you need.

Kind regards from Belgium,

Kenny

Comment: Have you tried to sort your values array by date ?

Comment: Also, does this look like what you are trying to do? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Comment: @JulCh That seems to be correct, my query was ordering by things in the wrong order, moving date to the second ordering item seems to have fixed my issue, I thank you dearly!